# Permission denied when copying a DLL

Tags: windows-7, permissions, dll

Windows is denying me permission to copy a dll from a mounted image. It says I need permission from all users to make any changes to the above mentioned file.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try in safe mode or if u are an admin than go through that account.

Comment: Which dll? Where are you pasting it? Are you trying to replace an existing dll? Do you have administrator rights?

Comment: If nothing of the solutions below works, try an Ubuntu Live Image.

Comment: Does Windows deny reading the DLL to copy or does Windows deny writing the DLL to the location where you want to copy it? Are you overwriting an existing DLL?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/).

> If you've ever been unable to delete a file in Windows, and can't
>   figure out what program's using it, Unlocker is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking ownership of the file.

Have a look at this [guide](http://neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=1257)